# How can I view old chat messages I've written?

Tags: support, chat, archive

Stack Overflow has a great archive of past comments, questions, answers, votes and so on. However, I can't seem to find a record of my past chat messages. Is this something that is archived? If so, then how can I access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Everything is archived with the individual room transcripts, but you cannot get a list of just your own messages.

You can search for specific messages said by a user, on the search page, by filling in their user ID. But you need to include a query, you cannot leave the field blank.

> [image: search form]

Result:

> [image: search result]

Comment: You can also view the most recent tab on a user chat profile which isn't great if they're a heavy chat user as it's not going to include "archive" things,  for instance, the OP's recent activity is [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1709033/henrywright?tab=recent) and it doesn't appear they've used chat for 3+ years, but it'll give them an idea in this case. (Appears to be 3 rooms auto-generated from extended discussion on main site posts)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this is possible. Even though it's not exposed in the interface, the "recent messages" tab in your profile supports pagination.

After seeing your most recent messages at:
[`https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1709033/henrywright?tab=recent`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1709033/henrywright?tab=recent)

You can find the next page at:
[`https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1709033/henrywright?tab=recent&page=2`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1709033/henrywright?tab=recent&page=2)

And continue from there.

Comment: That is ... an awesome trick ...

Comment: What rene said :) Any other hidden tricks you can share?

Comment: @Stijn I don't if it is covered there, but we have *[What are the hidden features of Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211)*.

Comment: Yeah, this is awesome and good to know. I wonder why this is not accessible from the user profile...